# C# How to assign i and j in 2D array when i press on a button

Tags: c#, oop

I was asked to make a tic tac toe in windows form and i have to use 2D array
I am trying to store 1 in the array for each X and -1 for each 0
then i will add the values in each row ,column and diagonal and check if its 3 or -3

the problem is i don't know how to assign and i and j for each element in the array after i press on a corresponding button

```
     private void storeInboard(int i, int j, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            {
                if ((sender as Button).Text == "X")
                    board[i][j] = 1;
                else if ((sender as Button).Text == "O")
                    board[i][j] = -1;
            }
    }
```

here i check for each column by giving its number

```
 private bool checkCol(int col)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            rowSum += board[i][col];
            if (colSum == 3 || colSum ==-3 )
                return true;
            else
                colSum = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

checking for winner

```
    private bool checkWinner()
    {
        return (checkCol(0) || checkCol(1) || checkCol(2) || checkDiag1() || checkDiag2() || checkRow(0) || checkRow(1) || checkRow(2));
    }
```

here is the button click event >> its is assigned for all the buttons

```
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (turn)
        {
            (sender as Button).Text = "X";
        }
        else
            (sender as Button).Text = "O";
        turn = !turn;
        turnCount++;
        (sender as Button).Enabled = false;
        if (checkWinner() && turnCount <=9)
            MessageBox.Show("Winner !!!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Tie -.-");
```

so I just want to know how can i send an i and j for the event storeInboard for each button i click
thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear on how your buttons are setup.  Do you have a pair for each of the 9 positions, or just one for X and one for O?  If the former then give them unique names like X00, X01, ... X22.  If the latter then you need to include some other way for the user to select the cell they are putting an X or O into.

Comment: I added just 9 buttons that their text can be changed to X or O .. and the cell is selected by pressing on the button in the GUI >> i just can't link the buttons with the array

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about arrays or some 2D stuff but binding information to winform controls.

You have several ways to do this.

1) In visual studio property panel fill buttons Tag property with an ordinal number one by one from left to right starting with zero. Left-upper button = 0, middle-upper = 1 and so on.
Then in button_click you can do something like:

```
var tag = int.Parse((string)((Button)sender).Tag);
int colIndex = tag % 3; 
int rowIndex = tag / 3;
```

2) Maybe the buttons are placed in a Panel. Then you can iterate through the children of the parent panel in button_click and see if one equals to sender.

```
    int c = 0;
    foreach (var item in parentPanel.Controls)
    {
        if (item == sender)
            break;
        c++;
    }
    if (c<parentPanel.Controls.Count) // found
    {
        int colIndex = c % 3;
        int rowIndex = c / 3;
    }
    // else -- ugh, something went wrong, maybe not only the buttons have this event
```

Much more solution is possible.